# Best way to generate a PDF from a template

Tags: c#, templates, pdf-generation

In a C# application, I must generate a pdf document from a specific template wich includes fields and images.

So I've thought of creating a ".tex" which would be my template, then modify it from the application and finally use a API to get a PDF file from the ".tex" file

But I also heard of some API to generate a PDF file directly without using latex. However, I think that it will not be easy to reproduce the template with the API.

What is the easiest way and the best API ?

Comment: Take a look at this http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/ and this http://pdfsharp.com/PDFsharp/.

Comment: What would be your ideal template? A word editor document or do you actually want to use a ".tex" file?

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend creating a HTML template and then converting it to PDF via https://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/ .

You can utilize Razor templating engine and get good Visual Studio support for creating you templates.

Its also easier to debug and fine-tune the result in a browser.

You can also find people to write HTML templates more easily.